# Is the following the correct usage for the word "read": "Read a dictionary"

Tags: verbs, nouns

Is it correct to state: "Read a dictionary". Similarly can you "Read an encyclopedia",

Comment: They're books.  What ELSE would you do with them??

Comment: I have spent many happy hours reading the *OED*, which is far more interesting than most novels.

Comment: Parhaps there’ll be popple who love to read dictionaries. But I don’t think I’ve read a dictionary just for pleasure like reading a novel, essay or manga. I just consult with, or check dictionary to look for definition, usage, pronunciation, or etymology of a word.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, and the word "read" totally works in that scenario.

You can also:

- search the dictionary
- scour the dictionary
- consult the dictionary
- look up something in the dictionary
- familiarize yourself with the dictionary
- memorize the dictionary
- love the dictionary
- become one with the dictionary

The dictionary is a wonderfully versatile book that you can do any number of worthwhile things with.

Comment: consult a dictionary

Comment: @dwjohnston It has been added.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using a dictionary to answer a specific question, I would consider the default wording to be that you "consult a dictionary" or "refer to a dictionary".

Of course reading is how you get the information, so it's not wrong to say you are reading the dictionary.  However, that usage has the connotation that you are reading the dictionary as a whole text, as you would a novel.

In other words, "I read the encyclopedia article" or "I read the dictionary entry" is normal usage but "I read the encyclopedia" implies you read *the whole thing.*